# Java tem Default Param Value?

Tags: java

Dá para definir o valor de um parâmetro em Java?

Procurei pela internet mas não encontrei nenhuma resposta satisfatória o suficiente, podem me ajudar?

O exemplo:

```
public User3(String fristName, String lastName) {
    this.fristName = capitalize(fristName);
    this.lastName = capitalize(lastName);
    this.fullName = fristName + " " + lastName;
}
 
public static String capitalize(String str) {
  if(str == null || str.isEmpty()) {
    return str;
  }

  return str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
}
```

Gostaria que o construtor receba um terceiro parâmetro, mas que tenha um valor *default* caso não seja informado. Algo assim:

```java
public User3(String fristName, String lastName, boolean show = true) {
    if (show == true) {
        System.out.println("usuario criado");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em Java não dá para fazer da forma que você quer, o que daria para fazer é sobrecarregar o construtor:

```
public User3(String firstName, String lastName, boolean show) {
    this.firstName = capitalize(firstName);
    this.lastName = capitalize(lastName);
    this.fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
    if (show) {
        System.out.println("usuario criado");
    }
}

public User3(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this(firstName, lastName, true);
}
```

Assim, se você chama com dois argumentos (`new User3(firstName, lastName)`), ele chama a versão com três argumentos usando o valor `true` para o terceiro argumento. Se quiser que o valor seja `false`, tem que chamar explicitamente: `new User3(firstName, lastName, false)`.

Repare também que valores booleanos não precisam ser comparados da forma que você fez. Em vez de `if (show == true)`, basta fazer `if (show)` (de forma similar, `if (! show)` é o equivalente a `if (show == false)`).

> Obs: também corrigi o nome da variável de `fristName` para `firstName`.

---

Uma opção pior é usar varargs:

```java
public User3(String firstName, String lastName, Object... params) {
    this.firstName = capitalize(firstName);
    this.lastName = capitalize(lastName);
    this.fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;

    if (params.length >= 1 && params[0] != null) {
        if (Boolean.class.isInstance(params[0]) && ((Boolean) params[0]).booleanValue()) {
            System.out.println("usuario criado");
        }
    }
}
```

É pior porque agora você pode passar um ou mais objetos de qualquer tipo, portanto não fica claro que ele aceita apenas um valor booleano (qualquer outro tipo e argumentos adicionais são ignorados). A primeira forma sugerida acima é mais direta e indicada.

Comment: aeeeee funcionou, obrigado!!!